# A Nodal curve embedded in a smooth variety, is always regularly embedded?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I will consider more simple situation. Let C be a nodal curve which is a union of two $\mathbb{P}^1$, $C_1,C_2$. Which meets at a node $p$.
Consider $C$ is embedded in a smooth variety $Y$. Assume that tangent directions $T_pC_1,T_pC_2$ are transversal in $T_pY$.

Then, is $C$ embedded in $Y$ regularly? Which means $I_{C/Y}/I_{C/Y}^2$ is locally free.

I think this is true but i cannot make a proof directly.

Comment: This is just a question for the formal neighborhood of the node, right? And then it's enough to say that $C$ is a local complete intersection? Is it true that $C_1 \cup C_2$ lies in a smooth surface inside this formal neighborhood in $Y$?

Comment: If $C_1$ and $C_2$ meets transversally at $p$, is it possible that there is no smooth surface containing $C$ in a formal neighborhood??

Comment: No, it's not possible: look at the generators of the ideal of C, and choose among those the elements whose differentials at p are linearly independent. They will cut out a subvariety that is smooth at p, and its tangent space is the same as C, which makes it a surface.

Comment: t3suji//thanks, then you think that it is true that $C$ is embeded regularly in this situation??

Comment: I think so, it is a local complete intersection, like Allen Knutson says.

Comment: In other words: locally around $p$ (for the classical or étale topology), the embedding $C\hookrightarrow Y$ is isomorphic to $C \hookrightarrow T_p(C)\hookrightarrow T_p(Y)$, which is regular because it is the composition of two regular embeddings.